# How can I convert all numbers in a dataset of a DOM node into JavaScript numbers

Tags: javascript

I use the `data` attribute to store strings and numbers in DOM nodes and read them with JavaScript. Unfortunately all values in the `dataset` are saved as string. So whats is the best way to convert them into numbers but leave the strings.

html:

```
<input data-minvalue="10" data-startcolor="#00ee00"/>
```

expected result:

```
{
  minvalue: 10,
  startcolor:'#00ee00'
}
```

**Edit:**

- it has to work with int and float
- should not convert '12_test'
- should convert '.3'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precede the value by `+`, which will convert it to a number natively and preserves stuff like `12_test`, which `parseFloat` does not. If the result `isNaN`, then safe the string instead.

```
function kittenBaloon(str) {
    var num = +str;

    if(isNaN(num)) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}

console.log(kittenBaloon('12_test'));
console.log(kittenBaloon('.3'));
console.log(kittenBaloon('#00ee00'));
```

Comment: excelent solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Number` function to parse numeric values. If it is not numeric, you get a `NaN`.

```
var dataset = el.dataset;
var data = {};
Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function (key) {
  var num = Number(dataset[key]);
  data[key] = isNaN(num) ? dataset[key] : num;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If parsing the attribute and checking for [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) is not enough, you will have to test via regex whether you want to parse it as a number or not:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i=0; i<node.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attr = node.attributes.length;
    if (attr.name.substr(0, 5) == "data-")
        obj[attr.name.substr(5)] = /^[+-]?(\d*\.)?\d+(e[+-]?\d+)?$/i.test(attr.value)
          ? parseFloat(attr.value)
          : attr.value;
    }
}
```

This regex orientates on the *numeric string grammar* as found in [EcmaScript §9.3.1](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1); yet it for example does not allow whitespaces.

Comment: only works with `ints`and you can use `node.dataset` to get all data attributes

Comment: I didn't use `node.dataset` because it is not supported in older browsers. Of course, if that's not a constriction for the OP the loop could be much easier (and the property names would be parsed different).

Answer (score 0):

You would use the parseInt() method.

After you pull the attr value for data-minvalue from the html you would pass it to parseInt() and use that as the value in your object.

assuming the use of jquery

```
var obj = {};
var strNum = $('selector').attr('data-minvalue);
var intNum = parseInt(strNum);
obj.minvalue = intNum;
```

Comment: `parseInt(strNum, 10)` _Always_ include the radix parameter! Even though it is "optional", it is _not optional_.

Comment: If you need floating point then use parseFloat() not parseInt(), I agree with @michael-berkowski

Comment: @dafi see my edited question, simple parseFloat/parseInt will not work.

Comment: my apologies on only applying to ints, got tunnel vision since an int was used in the example

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1 = "#456456";
var string2 = "546.789";

var filterString = function (string) {
    var temp = string;
        regex1 = /\./;
        regex2 = /\D/g;

    temp = temp.replace(regex1, '');

    if (!regex2.test(temp)) {
        return parseFloat(string);

    }

    return string;

}

string1 = filterString(string1);
string2 = filterString(string2);

console.log(typeof string1); //returns string
console.log(typeof string2); //returns number
```